# dynamically added sub div in bootstrap grid not taking full width of the div

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a parent div and I am dynamically appending smaller divs with content to it. I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

The parent div code is as below:

```
<div class="row" style="float: left;">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" id="parent">
    </div>
</div>
```

The sub div's that I am appending inside the parent div is as below:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12" style="margin-top: 20px; padding: 10px; float: left;">
   <fieldset class="border p-2">
      <legend class="w-auto">Box</legend>
      <div style="width: 576px; float: left;">
         <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
      </div>
      <label for="student">Student</label>
      <span style="width: 576px;">
         <select style="width: 100%;" id="student" class="form-control select2 w-100">
            <option value="">Select Student</option>
            <option value="1">Student1</option>
         </select>
      </span>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

I want the sub div's to appear adjacent to each other(side by side) inside the parent div.But the problem here is that the controls like close button or the select list is not taking up the full width of the sub div. I explicitly added `style="width: 576px; float: left;"` so that they take up the width specified. Also, when the first div is added its not taking up the full width. Only when I add two sub divs, that they look good. How do I avoid adding explicit width. Could anyone please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Add `parent` to `display:grid;`. For more details about css grid layout see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I have update the code to match your image, does this do it for you? 
Added color **red** to show the col-md-12 section.

Code Update:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row col-md-12" style="background-color: red; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom:20px;">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">col-md-4</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">col-md-4</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">col-md-4</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but if we remove style="width: 576px;" from the controls it doesn't work. Ideally, it should take the width of the <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12" ></div>.

Comment: also, if I remove float: left, they do not appear side by side.

Comment: Updated the code, is this what you want? if not can you provide an image or something because then i don't really know what you want.

Comment: attached an image to my question above.

Comment: I want them to appear adjacent to each other, like what I have in my image.

Comment: click "run code snippet" and then press expand snippet, it goes to mobile view in bootstrap after a specific width.